# How to extract the who number of agents in an agentset? (NetLogo)

Tags: netlogo, agentset

I have a patch variable set as `visitantBees []`.
The intention is that each patch has a record of which agents were in it.
The method for registering the "visiting agents" is as follows:

```
to computing Frequency
  ask patches
  [
    if any? turtles-here
    [
      set visitantBees lput [who] of turtles-here visitantBees
    ]
  ]
end
```

However, this way a list of list is returned (`[[3 1 0 2 4]]`, for example).

Would anyone know how I can add only the `who` number to the `visitantBees` list?
Maybe a way to extract all the items from the `turtles-here`.

Comment: In NetLogo, it's almost never appropriate to ever use `who` numbers for anything at all. Involving `who` numbers makes your coding life harder, not easier. Instead, refer to the agents themselves directly. Also consider using agent sets instead of lists.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you get a list of lists is that both `visitantBees` and `[who] of turtles-here` are lists.

While `visitantBees` is a list because you set it as a list, why is `[who] of turtles-here` a list? Because `turtles-here` is an agentset - and the only way to report a variable of an agentset is to create a list. For example, if you wanted to know `[color] of turtles`, the only way NetLogo has to give you this information is to put all the turtles' colors in a list.

So, why is `turtles-here` an agentset? Because, even if sometimes `turtles-here` can contain 0 or 1 turtle, it can also contain multiple turtles. And anything that is fit to contain multiple agents has to be an agentset.

On the other hand, when you ask a single agent to report one of its variables, you get the value as such, i.e. not a list (unless that value is a list in itself, of course). For example, `[color] of turtle 0` is just its color, not a list containing a color.

Therefore, you can achieve your goal by individually asking every turtle on the patch to append their `who` to `visitantBees`:

```
to computingFrequency
  ask patches [
    ask turtles-here [
      set visitantBees lput who visitantBees
    ]
  ]
end
```

Or, given that turtles can automatically read and change the patches-own variables of the patch they are standing on, you can make it even simpler:

```
to computingFrequency
  ask turtles [
    set visitantBees lput who visitantBees
  ]
end
```

Which is also faster because it will only engage with turtles (who, by definition, are standing on a patch) rather than engaging with every patch even if there are no turtles on it.